# TypeError: object not callable when making instance

Tags: python

I've searched around other threads with similar questions, but I'm not finding the answer.  Basically, I have a class:

```
import Android_Class

class Android_Revision(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # dict for storing the classes in this revision
        # (format {name : classObject}):
        self.Classes = {}
        self.WorkingClass = Android_Class()
        self.RevisionNumber = ''

    def __call__(self):  
        print "Called"

    def make_Class(self, name):
        newClass = Android_Class(name)
        self.Classes.update({name : newClass})
        self.WorkingClass = newClass

    def set_Class(self, name):
        if not(self.Classes.has_key(name)):
            newClass = Android_Class(name)
            self.Classes.update({name : newClass})
        self.WorkingClass = self.Classes.get(name)
```

I'm trying to make an instance of this class:

```
Revision = Android_Revision()
```

and that's when I'm getting the error.  I'm confused because I have another situation where I'm doing almost the exact same thing, and it's working fine.  I can't figure out what differences between the two would lead to this error.  Thanks.

Comment: `Android_Class` is the name of a module. Are you sure you didn't mean to write `from Android_Class import Android_Class` or something similar?

Comment: What is the exact content (message) of the error? Which line does it reference? What does the "_almost the exact same thing_" look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second the comments, this question lacks important information, and if this error wasn't insanely common and had rather distinctive symptoms, I wouldn't be able to provide anything resembling an answer.

Python's view on {files,modules} and classes is quite different from Java's. A module is a higher-level unit of organization than classes. Specifically, a module may contain any number of classes (among numerous other things). `import` deals with modules, not with classes. `import foo` gives you the module of that name, regardless of any classes of that name. If you must have a class in a module of the same name (quite often, this is a sign of overusing classes or ignoring modules as unit of organization), you either access it as `Foo.Foo` or you do `from Foo import Foo`.

By the way, module names should be `lower_case` while class names should be `PascalCase`. Don't mix the two. Also read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for other conventions.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question.  My problems definitely came from thinking of classes/modules in a Java context, and your simple explanation was super helpful.  I fixed the issue.